# console.log multiple, formatted lines

Tags: javascript, line-breaks, console.log

I am currently trying to display multiple, formatted lines in the developer console. Formatting the string isn't a problem, but whatever I try, the line break will be ignored and it becomes a one liner:

```js
console.log('%c01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010%c1%c0%c1%c0101\n%c010101010%c1%c0%c1%c0%c1%c0%c10%c1%c0101%c0%c10%c1%c0%c1%c0%c1%c0%c1%c0%c101010101010101010%c1%c0%c1%c0%c10101', "background: #000; color: #000", "background: #000; color: #010405", "background: #000; color: #062534", "background: #000; color: #020a0e", "background: #000; color: #000", "background: #000; color: #000", "background: #000; color: #000203", "background: #000; color: #01090d", "background: #000; color: #03131a", "background: #000; color: #051a25", "background: #000; color: #06222e", "background: #000; color: #072837", "background: #000; color: #082e3f", "background: #000; color: #09384d", "background: #000; color: #0a394f", "background: #000; color: #083144", "background: #000; color: #082e3f", "background: #000; color: #062635", "background: #000; color: #062330", "background: #000; color: #051e29", "background: #000; color: #051a25", "background: #000; color: #03131b", "background: #000; color: #030f15", "background: #000; color: #01090c", "background: #000; color: #010304", "background: #000; color: #000", "background: #000; color: #010305", "background: #000; color: #05202c", "background: #000; color: #0d4f6d", "background: #000; color: #093449", "background: #000; color: #000");
```

Comment: What's the expected output? [It seems to format just fine for me](https://i.imgur.com/mgrraoF.png)

Comment: The expected output is multiline. And for me, [it does not work as expected](https://i.imgur.com/KNoFH2Q.png).

Comment: Ok, so it works in FF, not in Chrome and partly in Edge